# Conditionallly executing a method - in a beautifuly way

Tags: scala

Assuming the following:

```
  /**
 * the importer trait that glues extractor , transformator and loader together
 * (mini etl)
 */
trait Importer[A, B, C] {

  //this makes sure that the importer 
  //implements an extractor, a transformator and a loader (selfytping)

  self: Extractor[A, B] with Transformator[B, C] with Loader[C] =>

  /**
   * this is the method call for chaining all events together
   */
  def importAndTransformData(dataSource: A): Unit =
    {

      /**
       * perform initializations if necessary
       */
      initializeExtractor
      /**
       * extraction step
       */
      val output = extract(dataSource: A)

      /**
       * before the loading takes place we initialize the Loader if required
       */
      initializeLoader
      /**
       * conversion method that gets injected the load method
       */
      val transformed = transform(output, load)

      /**
       * perform actions afterwards if required
       */
      cleanupExtractor

      cleanupLoader

    }
```

The initilization methods currently have a dummy implementation  doing nothing.
And it is up to the concrete trait / subclass to overwrite it if needed.
This seems to be a bit clumsy.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for polymorphism!

Comment: In what way? I thought about annotations like in Junit

Comment: @StefanKunze just say so in concrete implementation of doSomething: `def doSomething() { initialize(); some work; postProcess() }`

Comment: This question is not entirely clear.. perhaps some examples?

Comment: Sure, heres the sample: (see updated op)

Answer (score 0):

A class should do just one thing and one thing alone:

- An Extractor should know how to extract and nothing else
- A Transformer should know how to transform and nothing else
- A Loader should know how to load and nothing else
- An Importer should know how to import, given an Extractor, Transformer and Loader

That is, the Importer should definitely not implement all the E-T-L methods. It should receive or create the E-T-L objects and use them appropriately.

I would make the E-T-L components self-contained units. They should know how to take care of themselves: initialize when constructed, and cleanup when they go out of scope.

I've done this kind of thing in Java + dependency injection with Spring. My Importer is truly glue-code, simply combining the E-T-L components which it receives configured by Spring, in one line of code.

If you rethink your design in terms of the do-only-one-thing principle, your question might naturally disappear. Since you're using Scala, try to avoid mutations, as that naturally drives you toward cleaner interfaces. (I mention this because your initialize* methods sound like they would modify state.)

Comment: thank you i do know about separation of concerns. the importer trait is also receiving a component named extractor, transformator and loader. so this is achieved. also writing to a database is inherently side effecty.

Comment: @StefanKunze and if you redesign this way (without importer trying to implement E-T-L), it still doesn't help?